# how to create custom layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

first sorry for my bad English, I am new to custom layout how to create custom layout like below image any one help me how to design it ,I m already search in google but i did't any solution so,please any one help me how to do that
[image]

Comment: have you tried any code then paste here. OR please specify some more detail exactly what you need.

Comment: I don't know how can i start this layout please help me how to do this

Comment: Some sort of code helps you here like top action bar  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Comment: thnq ,i m created action bar , how to create layout like that

Comment: You will get some idea about layouts in android from link http://androidexample.com/Linear_Layout_Basic-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=72&aaid=96

Comment: yes i got it but how to display multiple list view in single activity like above screen

Comment: You need Horizontal Recycler view.Link help you to understand recylerview . https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156 & other link  http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2014/11/simple-recyclerview-example-in-android.html

Comment: `display multiple list view in single activity` And where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1.`TextView` and a `Button`
2. The 2nd seems to be just a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` which has been inflated by an item layout which has an `ImageView` and 3 `TextViews` vertically. I'm sure you are getting the idea.

3.`TextView` and `Button` again
4. Same like 2nd view but inflated with just `ImageView`